# Replying to all recipients with Notmuch and msmtp

Tags: doom, notmuch

I have tested sending an email to multiple recipients with Notmuch through msmtp and it works. I can also copy all recipients of email to kill-ring (via `notmuch-show-stash-to`), no problem. However, when I reply all (with "R", actually "c R" since I am on Doom Emacs), the reply message is only addressed to one of the recipients, not all of them. Can anybody help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This was not a problem actually. I had listed all my accounts in Notmuch setup and I was testing by sending emails to myself. And it only sends an email to one of your accounts. I tried replying to an email with multiple recipients other than myself and it totally works. My only problem now is to figure out how to control which of my emails is used to send the reply, other than manually entering the correct email in the from header every time (and also adjusting the ... writes accordingly).